# Why won't tailwind find my dynamic class?

Tags: tailwind-css

so i'm trying to load classes dynamically based on an Object Array

```
<div v-for="item in items"
     :key="item.id"
     :class="'text-' + item.color + '-600'"
>
{{ item.name }}
</div>
```

i checked on the Elements Panel on the browser and the class property loads correctly but the css doesn't.

Why is that so? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Tailwind generates a CSS file containing only the classes used in your project. It can't recognise the dynamically generated class name you're using so doesn't include it in the output file.

To quote the documentation:

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as complete unbroken strings in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#class-detection-in-depth

I answered a similar question on this subject recently: [Fontawesome icons not accepting color props through react functional components via tailwindcss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71791472/fontawesome-icons-not-accepting-color-props-through-react-functional-components/)

---

To resolve the issue, either pass in the full class name or safelist it instead.

Comment: thanks for the help! Decided to just pass the whole class and it works fine

Comment: Not sure how, but @HanirTxZ approach also works for me. Using Nuxt3 and Tailwind.

Comment: @InvisibleGorilla You're no longer dynamically generating class names but rather passing through the full name. That's the correct solution. The previous commenter was merely stating they'd taken the suggestion at the end of my answer.

Comment: @NathanDawson - can you have a look here? I am passing full class name, on the iteration adding the class. but not works. what would be the correct approach here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74861826/applying-the-class-name-through-json-not-working-same-works-if-hardcoded/74864791#74864791

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who needs it, here's what *"safelist it instead"* means in @NathanDawson's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71819163/1891677):

**tailwind.config.js**

```js
const usedColors = ['blue', 'red', 'green']
module.exports = {
  safelist: usedColors.map((c) => `text-${c}-600`),
  /* rest of your tailwind config */
}
```

And, if you want to add some `line-clamp-*` dynamically generated classes, which can either output `line-clamp-2` or `line-clamp-4` to the above:

```js
const safelist = [
  ...['blue', 'red', 'green'].map((c) => `text-${c}-600`),
  ...[2, 4].map((n) => `line-clamp-${n}`)
]
console.log(safelist)
/* 
[ 
  'text-blue-600',
  'text-red-600',
  'text-green-600',
  'line-clamp-2',
  'line-clamp-4'
]
*/
  
module.exports = {
  safelist,
  /* rest of your tailwind config */
}
```

The idea is to generate an array of strings containing all the classes you want included in the built stylesheet, regardless of the fact Tailwind doesn't find them in your code.