# Injecting dynamic value in tailwind CSS styles

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a variable, `NAV_HEIGHT` which holds a value I need to inject into multiple tailwind styles.

```
import { NAV_HEIGHT } from '../../constants'

const Nav = () => {
  return (
    <nav className={`h-${NAV_HEIGHT} fixed bg-blue-500 w-full`}>
...
```

in another component I need the value of `NAV_HEIGHT` to be applied to a `pt-${NAV_HEIGHT}`

Which is the best practice for doing this?

Comment: This won't work. Tailwind doesn't support dynamic sizing.

Comment: @Liam there is no support to do this at all?

Comment: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names <- No

Comment: Tailwind classes use tree shaking, you can 't tree shake a dynamic string like that as it has no idea what all the variations of NAV_HEIGHT will be

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why won't tailwind find my dynamic class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71818458/why-wont-tailwind-find-my-dynamic-class)

Comment: Answered multiple times, e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71063619/react-and-tailwind-css-dynamically-generated-classes-are-not-being-applied/71068925#71068925

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React and Tailwind CSS: dynamically generated classes are not being applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71063619/react-and-tailwind-css-dynamically-generated-classes-are-not-being-applied)