# problem while rendering dynamic class using tailwind and react

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am rendering a different options of color using dynamic colors in tailwind
here is the code:

```
import React from "react";

const Tab1: React.FC = () => {
  const colorOptions = [
    ["indigo-500", "indigo-700"],
    ["purple-500", "purple-700"],
    ["rose-400", "rose-600"],
    ["orange-400", "orange-600"],
    ["gray-400", "gray-600"],
  ];

  return (
    <div className="">
      <div className="flex my-3 py-2">
        {colorOptions.map((colors, index) => (
          <div
            key={index}
            className={`h-12 w-12 rounded-full bg-gradient-to-r from-${colors[0]} to-${colors[1]} cursor-pointer mx-2`}
          ></div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Tab1;
```

but only purple is getting rendered and all the other colors are just appearing as white,
also in the browser I can see the classes are correct

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71818458/why-wont-tailwind-find-my-dynamic-class) will help you resolve this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why won't tailwind find my dynamic class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71818458/why-wont-tailwind-find-my-dynamic-class)

Comment: yes , got the ans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

You could consider:

- Using full class names in definitions, like:

  ```
  const Tab1: React.FC = () => {
    const colorOptions = [
      ["from-indigo-500", "to-indigo-700"],
      ["from-purple-500", "to-purple-700"],
      ["from-rose-400", "to-rose-600"],
      ["from-orange-400", "to-orange-600"],
      ["from-gray-400", "to-gray-600"],
    ];

    return (
      <div className="">
        <div className="flex my-3 py-2">
          {colorOptions.map((colors, index) => (
            <div
              key={index}
              className={`h-12 w-12 rounded-full bg-gradient-to-r ${colors[0]} 
  ${colors[1]} cursor-pointer mx-2`}
            ></div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };
  ```
- [Safelisting](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes) the classes you will use, like:

  ```js
  /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
  module.exports = {
    safelist: [
      'from-indigo-500',
      'from-purple-500',
      // etc.
    ]
    // Or
    safelist: [
      { pattern: /^from-(indigo-5|purple-5|rose-4|orange-4|gray-4)00$/ },
      { pattern: /^to-(indigo-7|purple-7|rose-6|orange-6|gray-6)00$/ },
    ]
    // etc.
  }
  ```